# I get wrong response when i fetch wikipedia api

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, wikipedia-api

I get this response when I try to use Wikipedia API

> Response {type: "cors", url: "https‍://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensear…amespace=0&format=json&origin=*&utf8=&format=json", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

The correct response is a JSON format of requested data, but I can't get it!

Here's my code:

```
let link = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=google&limit=20&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*&utf8=&format=json`;
fetch(link)
.then((res)=>{console.log(res);return res;})
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)

```js
let link = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=google&limit=20&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*&utf8=&format=json`;
fetch(link)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: @ZeyadEtman,if the problem has been solved,you can close this question by accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

**try this** [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/f9tsu21k/648/)

```
fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=google&limit=20&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*&utf8=&format=json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```